System Freezes During Parallel Calculations with Python GridSearchCV and WIEN2k on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Hello Ubuntu Community,
I'm experiencing system freezes when running parallel calculations using both Python (GridSearchCV with RandomForestRegressor) and WIEN2k. The system becomes unresponsive, requiring a manual restart. Below are my system specs and the steps I've taken to troubleshoot the issue:
System Specifications:
CPU: Intel Core i9-14900KF
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 SUPER
Motherboard: ASUS ROG STRIX Z790-H GAMING WIFI
RAM: 32GB DDR5
Storage: 2TB NVMe
OS: Dual Boot - Windows 11 and Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
The system freezes without any error message, especially when executing parallel tasks. This occurs with a Python script involving GridSearchCV and RandomForestRegressor, and also during parallel computations with WIEN2k. I tried updating and upgrading everything and every driver. The issue is when this happens system monitor or htop or other commands do not work. The running command just disappears without any error.
During parallel run with Wien2K package, it runs several iterations and then the running process disappear and system freezes. When this happens even with root rebooting it goes to a black screen and I have to restart with pc button.
I have assigned swap more than my RAM. I do not know what to do anymore. Any advice?

I suggest you look into getting some details on the 2 apps in question on what kind of hardware and OS they need. It certainly sounds like your computer as good as it is is just not up to the task.
